# How to check if method parameter type/return type is generic, in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, code-analysis, roslyn

As stated in the title, I want to check if a method params are generic + if the return type of a method is generic.

For example:

```
    public ISet<string> Collect(MethodDeclarationSyntax method, SemanticModel semanticModel)
    {
        return method
            .ParameterList
            .Parameters
            .Select(x => x.Type.ToString())
            .ToImmutableHashSet();
    }
```

Here I want to return all the types of the params for the `method` variable, that are not generic, but I can't find anything in the API to filter the results.

I have the same problem when checking if the return type of a method is generic.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to find out if the type is something like `List<int>` or `Dictionary<int, string>.KeyCollection`?

Comment: No - I just want to know if a params/return value are generic. For example for the following method:

`public static TValue GetOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(TKey key)`

I want to know if the `key` param is generic and if the return value `TValue` is also generic.

Comment: Ok, so I found I can access `ITypeSymbol.TypeKind` to find what I'm looking for. Not sure if it's the best approach, but it works.

Comment: And @svick, now that I think about it, I will indeed also need to find out the types of generic collections/interfaces like `IList<>`, `List<>`, etc. Do you have an idea, how I can do that?

Comment: What have to got so far?

Comment: @Peter Ritchie managed to find what I was looking for in the INamedTypeSymbol interface. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you have to work with.  If you have an `ArgumentListSyntax` and thus zero or more `ArgumentSyntax`es (`ArgumentListSyntax.Arguments`), you can get the type info from the argument expression:

```
var type = model.GetTypeInfo(argument.Expression).Type as INamedTypeSymbol;
```

And from there, the `IsGenericType` property.  For example:

```
Debug.Assert(type.IsGenericType);
```

And if you have a `MethodDeclarationSyntax` object of the method, you can see if the `ReturnType` property is a type of `GenericNameSyntax`:

```
Debug.Assert(methodDeclaration.ReturnType is GenericNameSyntax);
```

cast to `GenericNameSyntax` to get more information about the generic type like type arguments.